# What are nested patterns?

Tags: sml, smlnj

What are nested patterns? I can't understand why the following has nested patterns:

```
exception BadTriple

fun zip3 list_triple =
    case list_triple of
         ([],[],[]) => []
       | (hd1::tl1,hd2::tl2,hd3::tl3) => (hd1,hd2,hd3)::zip3(tl1,tl2,tl3)
       | _ => raise BadTriple

fun unzip3 lst =
    case lst of
         [] => ([],[],[])
       | (a,b,c)::tl => let val (l1,l2,l3) = unzip3 tl
                        in
                          (a::l1,b::l2,c::l3)
                        end
```

Also, I can't understand what is different between **nested pattern** and **nested case-expression** can i get some example about those things?

Answer (score 6):

A nested pattern is a pattern that contains other non-trivial patterns (where by "non-trivial" I mean "not a variable or wildcard pattern").

`([], [], [])` is a nested pattern because `(p1, p2, p3)` is a pattern (matching tuples) and `[]` is also a pattern (matching empty lists), which is here applied to the elements of the triple. Likewise `(hd1::tl1, hd2::tl2, hd3::tl3)` is a nested pattern because `(p1, p2, p3)` is a pattern and `hd1::tl1`, `hd2::tl2` and `hd3::tl3` are also patterns (matching non-empty lists).

A way to express the same thing without nested patterns would be to move the inner patterns into their own case expressions (though I wouldn't recommend it because, as you can see, it makes the code quite a bit more complicated):

```
case list_triple of
(x, y, z) =>
  case x of
  [] =>
    case y of
    [] =>
      case z of
      [] => []
      | _ => raise BadTriple
    | _ => raise BadTriple
  | hd1 :: tl1 =>
    case y of
    [] => raise BadTriple
    | h2 :: tl2 =>
      case z of
      [] => raise BadTriple
      | h3 :: tl3 =>
        (hd1,hd2,hd3)::zip3(tl1,tl2,tl3)
```

This is a nested case expression because we have a case expression that contains other case-expressions. The version with the nested patterns was not a nested case expression because there was only one case expression - not multiple inside each other.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will help if we decompose the function into curry style,
which does not have nested patterns,
in the foo function below there is only 3 (non-nested) patterns,

```
fun foo [] [] [] = []
  | foo (hd1::tl1) (hd2::tl2) (hd3::tl3) = (hd1, hd2, hd3)::zip3(tl1, tl2, tl3)
  | foo _ _ _ = raise BadTriple
and zip3 (l1, l2, l3) = foo l1 l2 l3
```

it is easy to see each individual pattern when we use the as keyword,
to the right of each **as** is a pattern.

```
fun zip3 (l1 as [], l2 as [], l3 as []) = []
  | zip3 (l1 as hd1::tl1, l2 as hd2::tl2, l3 as hd3::tl3) = (hd1, hd2, hd3)::zip3(tl1, tl2, tl3)
  | zip3 _ = raise BadTriple
```

So, why do we consider this nesting?

we can add the as for the initial argument **list_triple**,
and see that we in fact have patterns within a pattern.

```
fun zip3 (list_triple as (l1 as [], l2 as [], l3 as [])) = []
  | zip3 (list_triple as (l1 as hd1::tl1, l2 as hd2::tl2, l3 as hd3::tl3)) = (hd1, hd2, hd3)::zip3(tl1, tl2, tl3)
```

without as and the unused variables it will look much nicer.

```
fun zip3 ([], [], []) = []
  | zip3 (hd1::tl1, hd2::tl2, hd3::tl3) = (hd1, hd2, hd3)::zip3(tl1, tl2, tl3)
  | zip3 _ = raise BadTriple
```

Answer (score 1):

> what is nested patterns?

pattern in pattern is nested pattern.

---

> I can't understand why it is nested patterns

```
| (hd1::tl1,hd2::tl2,hd3::tl3) => ...
```

- *pattern* here: `(list1, list2, list3)`
- *nested pattern* here: `list1 -> hd1::tl1`, `list2 -> hd2::tl2`, `list3 -> hd3::tl3`

---

```
| (a,b,c)::tl =>
```

- *pattern* here: `tuple::t1`
- *nested pattern* here: `tuple -> (a, b, c)`

> Also i can't understand what is different between nested pattern and nested case-expression can i get some example about those things?

---

They are two different things. *Nested pattern* has been explained above. As for nested *case-expression*:

```
case something of              (*case here*)
| pattern =>
    case pattern of                (*nested case here*)
    | ...
```